# How do I create a global variable in NetLogo to monitor a specific turtle breed?

Tags: global-variables, netlogo, monitor

I am using NetLogo to create an age-structured model of disease transmission. I have multiple turtle breeds - e.g., `[persons1 person1]`, `[persons2 person2]`, etc. - in which their disease state is described by the agent variable, `state` (e.g., `state 1` is susceptible, `state 2` is infected, `state 3` is hospitalized, etc.). Each breed becomes infected at different rates and so I created a global variable, `hospitalizations`, that I am using to monitor the number of turtles who transition from infected to hospitalized at each timestep. For example:

```
ask turtles [
state 2
   if random_float 1 < lambda [
      set state 3
      set hospitalizations hospitalizations + 1
   ]
]
```

However, I would like to create distinct global variables of `hospitalizations` for each breed to monitor the number of persons within each breed that transition to hospitalized - e.g., `hospitalizations1` for `persons1`, `hospitalizations2` for `persons 2`, etc.. Rather than copying the lines of code above for each breed [e.g., `ask persons1`...`set hospitalizations1 hospitalizations1 + 1`], is there another way to do this without modifying `ask turtles`? For instance, something like: `set hospitalizations1 hospitalizations1 + 1 if persons1 = TRUE`?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you should write a good flowchart and organize the types of global variables and how to set them. In addition, NetLogo allows you to make use of the "if" and "ifelse" constructs, which can be combined to reduce the number of global variables. Furthermore, you can manage turtles that meet certain conditions by colouring them. This is a great way to reduce the number of global variables. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your breeds (persons1 and persons2) have turtle properties called state and the state will stay at state 3 as long as it is hospitalized. If that is the case, then I think you don't even need a global variable `hospitalizations`. Instead, you can monitor all of your turtles or a specific breed using [count command](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/count.html) like this :

```
;to count all breed
count turtles with [state = 3] 

;counting specific breed
count persons1 with [state = 3]
count persons2 with [state = 3]
```